# Application Design Issue - GWT

Tags: java, gwt, jakarta-ee

I want to desgin a web-site using GWT. Which will contain Header, Footer, Left Navigation and Central Navigationa and Right Navigation. I have tried many ways using DocLayout, Simplepanel and other things but couldn't accomplish what I want. I am looking for following things.

1. ApplicationDefaultLayout which have fixed header and footer.
2. Central area (leftnavigation,rightnavigation and mainarea) which can be changed on clicking the button in header.

Could you guys give me some idea so that I can accomplish it. I also wants every panel to be resizeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [SplitLayoutPanel](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwSplitLayoutPanel) .

I already using it in a project, and it works great ;)

Comment: Thanks for that ... let me try it too.

Comment: ok I am using the SplitLayoutPanel, but my problem is once I defined the application Default window ... I am not able to update that window later because it is not allowing me to add anything after adding the center element